# Splitting inside a flow in Akka-Streams

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am trying to come up with a solution to split an incoming String I am receiving into multiple Strings. I have been researching and it looks like in the previous versions of Akka-Streams there was a class `Transformer` that you could extend to do this kind of transformation.

In the version I am using (RC2) there are `Stage`s but I am not really sure how I can implement the splitting pattern.

```
Source.actorPublisher[String](MyActor.props).
.XXXXX(_.split("\n"))
.map(...)
.to(Sink(...))
```

I am looking for the `XXXXX` component that will allow me to input a `String` and return a sequence of `String` and will emit each one to the rest of the flow.

Comment: You can use `mapConcat` if the result elements always only depend on a single input element. You can use a (stateful) stage if the dependency is more complex.

Comment: As a addition to this generally `mapConcat` can be think of in terms of `flatMap`. The name differs because some monad law would not hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @jrudolph that `mapConcat` is probably what you are looking for.  A quick example showing this method in action:

```
  val strings = List(
  """hello
     world
     test
     this""",
     """foo
     bar
     baz
     """

  )

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
  implicit val mater = ActorFlowMaterializer()
  Source(strings).
    mapConcat(_.split("\n").map(_.trim).toList).
    runForeach(println)
```

If you run this code you will see the following printed out:

```
hello
world
test
this
foo     
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Akka provides the [`Framing`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#parsing-lines-from-a-stream-of-bytestrings) helper functions for this type of problem.

Assuming your charset is UTF-8 you can write a function that takes in the maximum size of the delimited `String` values and returns a `Flow` that can perform the splitting:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing
import akka.util.ByteString

val newLineSplitter : (Int) => Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = 
  (maxLineSize) =>
    Flow[String]
      .map(ByteString.apply)
      .via(Framing delimiter (ByteString("\n"), maxLineSize))
      .via(Flow[ByteString] map (_.utf8String))
```